# jQuery text() and html() behavior with script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to parse the contents of a `<script>` tag which contains an XML string, the structure is  similar to this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <script id="def" type="text/xml">
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <someroot>
                   <firsttag>
                       <script></script>
                   </firsttag>
                   <secondtag>
                       <a>asdsa</a>
                   </secondtag>
               </someroot>
           </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that neither text() nor html() picks up the whole content of the inline script tag and the output is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<someroot>
    <firsttag>
       <script>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gxEM/)

Is this the intended behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems like the `</script>`in your XML closes the script element, so I guess you could say it is the expected behaviour

Comment: You're closing the script. Naturally, the script ends there.

Comment: Why put XML in a `script` element in the first place? Even using an HTML comment would seem more appropriate. http://jsfiddle.net/3gxEM/5/

Comment: @cookiemonster the XML may contain several comments and this breaks your workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/Me8m6/. Why would be more appropriate to put XML in HTML comments instead of script tags?

Comment: Because `script` tags are for scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `</script>` in your XML closes the script element, so I guess you could say it is the expected behaviour